# Image from an imageview shows only black image when shared?

Tags: android, android-studio

Im trying to share an image which is displayed in an imageview.
But when shared, its showing a black screen, and on submit says "sharing failed"

### Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Code as follows

```
 collageImage.setImageBitmap(bmap1);
    Drawable mDrawable = collageImage.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.png");
    cachePath.mkdirs();
    try {
        cachePath.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/png");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
    Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/DCIM/Camera/image.png"));
    Intent openThree = new Intent(createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
    startActivity(openThree);
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Selected: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

LogCat

```
06-18 13:47:36.906 4429-4429/com.austurn.keikonew.keiko W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
06-18 13:47:36.907 4429-4429/com.austurn.keikonew.keiko W/System.err:     at com.austurn.keikonew.keiko.ThreeFragment$10.onClick(ThreeFragment.java:2122)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-18 13:47:36.909 4429-4429/com.austurn.keikonew.keiko W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-18 13:47:36.911 4429-4429/com.austurn.keikonew.keiko W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-18 13:47:37.034 4429-4440/com.austurn.keikonew.keiko I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1063(81KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 122MB/126MB, paused 26.566ms total 119.644ms
06-18 13:47:37.121 4429-4452/com.austurn.keikonew.keiko D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa43052a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa43032a0)
06-18 13:47:40.471 4429-4452/com.austurn.keikonew.keiko D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa43052a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa43032a0)
```

Gradle details as follows

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.austurn.keikonew.keiko"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

It was working in previous versions, and Android Studio earlier version. But the issue happened after version updates

Comment: Have you kept your target as Oreo? If yes then need to give runtime path permission using file provider. and need to register provider in manifest. Check this link : https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing

Comment: . No, i used Nougat. Do i need to give runtime permission. Thanks sameer

Comment: Yes from Nougat it's required.

Answer (score 0):

> add runtime permission code for Android 6.0 (API Level 23) and up, here is the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) or you can find [example here](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-read-write-external-storage-file-example/)

This is the code for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

```
if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Permission is granted");

    return true;
}
```

Ask for permission else like this

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this for updated versions:
For example:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            1);
                }
else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    profile_file_name = "profile_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), profile_file_name);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.hp.imageuploadapp.provider", f));
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }



public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            profile_file_name = "profile_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), profile_file_name);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.hp.imageuploadapp.provider", f));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);} 
else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

And Add the above in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

For above code you need to apply Runtime Read and Write Permission and your target is Nougat thats why you need to apply read path permission using file provider. And need to register provider in Android Manifest

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for giving me some clues. I searched all and get it worked. My code as follows

```
 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
                {
                    if (checkPermission())
                    {

                        try {
                            File file = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(),"logicchip.png");
                            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                            fOut.flush();
                            fOut.close();
                            file.setReadable(true, false);
                            final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                            intent.setType("image/png");
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via"));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else {
                        requestPermission(); // Code for permission
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }


 private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private void requestPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Write External Storage permission allows us to do store images. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .");
                } else {
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```